# Matplotlib custom ticks and grids in groups

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, xticks

I am trying to insert custom ticks to a plot in batches with defined distances. I can do this by manually adding them, but I am looking for a better way.

**Example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-5, 5]
y = [1, 5]
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.grid(axis="x", which='major', color='r', linestyle='--')

plt.yticks([])

# Adding custom ticks 
cticks = [-8, -7, -6, -5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.xticks(cticks)

plt.show()
```

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFufG.png)

Here's what I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [-5, 5]
y = [1, 5]
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.grid(axis="x", which='major', color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1 , 5, step=1))

plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuqFY.png)

But this gives only one batch.

**Question:** Is there a similar way to include more batches of tick marks and grids on the x-axis at desired positions?

Comment: What's the issue with the first method?

Comment: I was looking for an automated way of doing it by specifying only the batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you don't want to specify all ticks manually but only the batches. You can to this in a loop that will extend `cticks`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-5, 5]
y = [1, 5]
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.grid(axis="x", which='major', color='r', linestyle='--')

plt.yticks([])

# Adding custom ticks
cticks = []
for n in [-8, 1]: # specify the beginning of each batch here
    cticks += range(n, n+4)
plt.xticks(cticks)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]